# Sort FireStore data in ForEach after int value

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I am building this app related to a local motocross championship where you have the ranking of the riders. I have all the riders in firebase firestore and I figured out how to filter them upon the class but I am wondering how I can sort the list upon the position of the rider (ascending) inside the leaderboard so I can create the ranking. I am using an INT value called "poz" in order to determine the position in the leaderboard (1 = 1st etc)

Below you can find the code for my observer

```
class clasamentobserver: ObservableObject {

    @Published var riders = [riderData]()

    init() {

        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.collection("riders").addSnapshotListener{ (snap, err) in

            if err != nil{
                print((err?.localizedDescription)!)
                return
            }

            for i in snap!.documentChanges{

                if i.type == .added {

                    let id = i.document.documentID
                    let image = i.document.get("image") as! String
                    let nume = i.document.get("nume") as! String
                    let club = i.document.get("club") as! String
                    let poz = i.document.get("poz") as! Int
                    let mx = i.document.get("mx") as! String


                    self.riders.append(riderData(id: id, image: image, nume: nume, club: club, poz: poz , mx: mx))
                }

                if i.type == .removed {

                    let id = i.document.documentID

                    for j in 0..<self.riders.count {

                        if self.riders[j].id == id {
                            self.riders.remove(at: j)
                            return
                        }
                    }
                }

                if i.type == .modified {

                    let id = i.document.documentID
                    let image = i.document.get("image") as! String

                    for j in 0..<self.riders.count {

                        if self.riders[j].id == id {
                            self.riders[j].image = image
                            return

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here you can find the View

```
struct clasamentPage: View {

    @ObservedObject var clasamentObserver = clasamentobserver()
    var body: some View {

        ZStack{

            Color("background").edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

            ScrollView {
                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    ZStack {
                        if geometry.frame(in: .global).minY <= 0 {
                            Image("t.ciolpani")
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                                .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
                                .offset(y: geometry.frame(in: .global).minY/9)
                                .clipped()

                            LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.gray, Color.clear]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
                                .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
                                .offset(y: geometry.frame(in: .global).minY/9)
                                .clipped()

                        } else {
                            Image("t.ciolpani")
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                                .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height + geometry.frame(in: .global).minY)
                                .clipped()
                                .offset(y: -geometry.frame(in: .global).minY)

                            LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.gray, Color.clear]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
                                .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height + geometry.frame(in: .global).minY)
                                .clipped()
                                .offset(y: -geometry.frame(in: .global).minY)
                        }
                    }
                }.frame(height: 300)

                VStack() {

                    TopPost()

                    if clasamentObserver.riders.isEmpty {

                        Text("No Posts")
                            .fontWeight(.heavy)

                    }else {

                        ForEach(clasamentObserver.riders){item in

                                riderCard(image: item.image, nume: item.nume, club: item.club, poz: item.poz)

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
    }
}
```

Any tips would be extremely helpful! Thank you in advance!!

Comment: `db.collection("riders").orderBy("poz")...`? Also see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for `orderBy("poz")`:

```
db.collection("riders").orderBy("poz").addSnapshotListener{ (snap, err) in
```

I highly recommend checking out the Firebase documentation on [ordering and limiting data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data), for more information on how ordering works, and the pages around it for more information on queries in general.

Comment: Thank you very much! .order(by: "poz") did the trick just fine! You are a hero, sir